# "Разорвать" HTML-таблицу

Tags: html

Задача заключается в создании структуры шапки HTML-таблицы.
Таблица содержит порядка 100 столбцов, в день вносится одна запись(поясняю, так как отображение ведется в рамках одного дня). Можно ли каким то хитрым способом разделить эту таблицу (исключительно визуально!)?

Comment: Что значит "_разделить эту таблицу_"?

Comment: "разделить эту таблицу"  - разделить ее на несколько частей(визуально) при этом сохранить   функциональную целостность.

Comment: А что, кроме HTML можно использовать? CSS? JS?

Comment: К сожалению исключительно html

Comment: Тогда, увы, никак.

Comment: Благодарю, но подожду еще идей

Comment: Если Вам надо показывать несколько таблиц (одна ваша разделенная "чисто визуально"), при этом нельзя использовать CSS или JS - то вы можете лишь показывать их все одновременно одна под другой. Чистый HTML никакой динамики не подразумевает...

Answer (score 2):

Если таблица генерируется, то перед ее отрисовкой загоняем столбцы в JS, считаем общее количество столбцов, делим это значение на два и добавляем еще один столбец с пустым контентом в середину общего массива. Назначаем ему персональный стиль, который будет визуально разделять таблицу на две части. Как-то так короче.

**Обновление**

А как таблица заполняется? Просто можно замутить в цикле на пхп(или чем-то аналогичном) нечто подобное, но вводить столбец не после генерации, а во время нее, особенно если количество столбцов одинаковое или мы можем поделить общий массив столбцов на две части: 0-49 и 50 - N, где N=90..110 например.

**Обновление 2**

Задавай в шапку таблицы   (символ пробела) и будет пустое пространство. Или там пару штук их поставь типа `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

**Обновление 3**

Ну есть еще вариант: вставить в ячейку `<td></td>`, к которой есть доступ сразу код js(без всяких jquerry и подобного) в виде одной минимизированой строки, и уже туда записать что угодно. Ибо корп-системе будет глубоко положить какой текст вставлять, а браузер клиента в любом случае реализует все как надо.

Comment: Спасибо, но это вариант не подходит, исключительно html

Comment: Это старая корп система, оперировать могу только html, и таблица заполняется автоматически. Задаю лишь шапку таблицы

Comment: это была первая идея, но проблема в том что части таблицы необходимо расположить друг под другом (что бы не было горизонтальной прокрутки)

Comment: <tr><td><br /></td></tr>

сработало?

P.S.: Именно это и надо вставить в ячейку

Comment: Благодарю, как только доберусь попробую)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 border=1 rules=groups>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3<td>4<td>5<td>6<td>7</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Отличный, кстати, вариант. Я что-то даже забыл о таких приемах верстки таблицами.